# Page not found (404): django cannot match the path

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I don't understand why I am getting a 4040 error while it seems I have defiend everything correctly. The `Ticket` model class has instances saved in the database so `pk` from 1 to 5 also exists. The `html` template is the simplest possible just to figure out why django cannot get and render the requested instance. Note that I can see the instances in the `admin` page and also other paths like adding new ticket etc are working fine. Any help is appreciated:

**the path/page that I am trying to get:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ticket/1/
```

**app: urls.py**

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'ticket/<int:pk>/', views.ticket_detail, name='ticket_detail'),
]
```

**project: urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('mmrapp.urls')), 
]
```

**views.py**

```
def ticket_detail(request, pk):
    ticket=get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'mmrapp/ticket_detail.html',{'ticket':ticket})
```

**html**

```
{% extends 'mmrapp/__l_single_column.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block main_col %}
    <div class="ticket">
        <h2>Ticket: {{ticket.pk}}</h2>
    </div>  

{% endblock main_col %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, `<int:pk>` syntax is available only through `path` function ([introduced](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax) in Django 2.0), not `url`, so you should use `path` function or refuse of using this syntax and switch to the old regex one:

```
url(r'ticket/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.ticket_detail, name='ticket_detail')
```

Also you need to cast `pk` parameter in your view to `int` as all parameters captured with regex are strings.

Comment: path is deprecated I guess in django 1.11 that I am using, what would be the syntax with `url` then?

Comment: @Ibo edited the post. Also it was not deprecated in 1.11, in reverse, it was actually introduced only in Django 2.0 (compare [1.11 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) with [2.0 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/))

Comment: I tried to use path but I could not import it, I used `from django.urls import path` but it gives me `cannot import` error

Comment: I tried the regex you suggested and I am still getting 404, I also tried `url(r'ticket/?P<pk>/\d+/', views.ticket_detail, name='ticket_detail')`

Comment: @Ibo because there is no `path` function there in 1.11 :) Look at my latest edit about parameter cast, it is probably the cause of 404.

Comment: I changed the first line in views to this: `ticket=get_object_or_404(Ticket,pk=int(pk))` it is still giving me 404

Comment: @Ibo ok, can you please debug this a bit, just to understand what's going on wrongly? Make sure to keep parameter cast and regex that I posted.

Comment: now I am getting this error: `NoReverseMatch at /ticket/1/
Reverse for 'ticket_edit' not found. 'ticket_edit' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: @Ibo I assume you have somewhere in your templates something like `{% url 'ticket_edit' ... %}`, but I can't see any reference to `ticket_edit` in your app's `urls.py`, neither can Django probably, that's why you have this error.

Comment: wow! you are smart man! I had it commented out, but stupidly it was reading it, thanks a lot for the help!